# Arithemetic series addition

Tags: number-theory, summation, infinity

Lets say I have M= 1+2+3+4+5+6+7.... (to infinity)

and I have another sequence,N=   6+14+22+30..... (to infinity)

is it possible to say that N = 4M +2 ?

Or is there another way that I can write this?

Comment: You could write: "none of $\;M\,,\,N\;$ is well defined (i.e., none is a definite real number) and thus $\;N=4M+2\;$ is meaningless."

Answer (score 1):

Let your sequences be $m=1,2,3,4,5\dots, n=6,14,22,30,\dots$.  It is true that $n(i)=4m(i)-2$  Then your sums are $M(i)=\sum_{j=1}^ij=\frac 12j(j+1)$ and $N(i)=\sum_{j=1}^i8j-2=8M(i)-2i$.  Even after two terms we have $N(2)=20 \neq 8M(2)-2=22$

Comment: I was told that 4+8+12+16+20+24+28 can be written as 4(1+2+3+4+5....) does it not mean that anything that isn't a multiple of the original sequence can't be done?

Comment: I would not accept it as it indicates the sum goes on forever.  Given that the sum diverges, it is meaningless.  In my version, we truncate the two series at some point to get a finite sum.  There is also the problem of whether the $2$ applies term by term or to the whole sum.  Since $N,M$ seem to be the whole sum, the $2$ should be as well, but it is not correct at any term after the first.

Comment: I've seen my mistake, the 4M+2 formula actually applies to the odd numbers, rather than the natural numbers, that formula is in fact 8M-2

Comment: That is still the pattern between the terms of your series, not the whole series.  Between the terms it is always $8m(i)-2$, and only $4m(i)+2$ for $i=1$  See my correction.